# Group Array By Range Value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have this array [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7], may I group the array according to the range value, so get the final result:

`'1-3' = [1,1,2,2,2,3]; // Count is 6
'4-5' = [4,4,5]; // Count is 3
'6-7' = [6,6,6,7]; // Count is 4`

Comment: Yes, you may.   How are the ranges defined? Can they change? What do you expect the result to be? Do you want to count, or group? The question is a little vague.

Comment: Hey @salathe, sorry my english is bad, i have 'User' table in DB with column 'birth_date'.
Yes, I want to group users with ages 
{10-20 years, 21-30 years, and so on}, 
then count total users with specific age ranges. I want to create an HTML table like this
Age | Total users
10 to 20 | 20
21 to 30 | 58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need I believe is:

```
function array_get_range($array, $min, $max) {
    return array_filter($array, function($element) use ($min, $max) {
       return $element >= $min && $element <= $max; 
    });
}

$array = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7];

$range13 = array_get_range($array, 1, 3); // [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
$range45 = array_get_range($array, 4, 5); // [4, 4, 5]
$range67 = array_get_range($array, 6, 7); // [6, 6, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array with your ranges, then iterate through the values and through the ranges inside. If the current value is inside the range, add the record to the current range:

```
<?php
$numbers = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7];
$counts = [];
$counts[] = ["values"=> [1, 3], "records" => []]; // first value in "values" is min, second is max
$counts[] = ["values"=> [4, 5], "records" => []];
$counts[] = ["values"=> [6, 7], "records" => []];
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    foreach ($counts as $key => &$value) {
        if ($number >= $value["values"][0] && $number <= $value["values"][1]) { // if between the range, add it to the records
            $value["records"][] = $number;
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($counts as $count) {
    echo $count["values"][0]." - ".$count["values"][1]." = ".count($count["records"])." elements<br>";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/VQdtF)

Answer (score 0):

I think `array_intersect()` and `range()` with `sizeof()/count()` does a cleaner job for this task.  It eliminates the double-conditional.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2f963e72b21ced2c8cbf978886b2076b4939aea))

```
function count_range($array, $min, $max) {
    return sizeof(array_intersect($array, range($min, $max)));
}

$array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7];

echo count_range($array, 1, 3);  // 6 from [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
echo count_range($array, 4, 4);  // 2 from [4, 4]
echo count_range($array, 2, 7);  // 11 from [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

- `range()` creates a whitelist array of one or more consecutive integers.
- `array_intersect()` compares the input array and the whitelist array all at once.
- `sizeof()` is just an alias of `count()` to determine how many elements were retained.